# How can I create a file with FileWriter within my project file using relative path

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am using NetBean and glassFish for developing jsp website and its server.
In the server side, I have a java class which generate a text file using FileWriter:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("the-file-name.txt", true);
```

But I found that this file was saved in the directory of glassfish:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config

Also, by checking the path by the code:

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
```

the result is also the same with the above path.

How can I get the correct relative path, whether the path of the project or the path of this java file?

Comment: Change to ".\some_folder\the-file-name.txt"?

Comment: This class is called by a listener from web.xml:
<listener>
        <listener-class>data.StartUpListener</listener-class>
</listener>
I am thinking this may be the reason why I get the wrong relative path

Answer (score 1):

This gets the location of the class/jar you are running:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

The string path holds the absolute directory, and using somthing like
`path = path.replace("jars", "");`, you can find the root directory for the application. For example, if the jar is in the directory `C:\Program Files\Example\jars`, this would set path to
`C:\Program Files\Example\`

Comment: I also tried this method but I also get the same path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config

As I said in the previous comment I think this is cause by the method is called by listener from web.xml

Comment: That must be, because this worked just fine for me. What about calling a via method, or whatever you want to call it, so you're basically encapsulating the main method that get's the path

Answer (score 0):

In Servlet

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/").replace("\\", "/");
```

In JSP

```
String filePath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/").replace("\\", "/");
```